# С# WinForms, Окно без рамки, Проблема с BorderTop

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, border

Убрал системное меню и тайтел у формы, но оставил рамку sizable(для того, чтобы можно было изменять размер).

Проблема заключается в том, что верхний бордер почему-то в 6px толщиной.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это пофиксить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код и метку фреймворка правильную поставьте. От Visual Studio и Border пользы ровно 0

Comment: Подредактировал)

Comment: На представленном скриншоте ControlBox на месте. Похоже, вы показываете что-то не то. / Также могу предположить, что у вас перегружен метод `WndProc`. Не?

Comment: Это не controlBox, это Panel)) “перегружен WndProc” ? Я ничего не добавлял в него.

Comment: Ещё раз: если `ControlBox = false`, то у формы не должны быть кнопок `_ □ x`, а они есть. Вы показываете какой-то левый скриншот. Точка.

Comment: Да нет))) Кнопки рисованные - на panel-и!!!